# Connecting to SFTP server via Windows' Command Prompt

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, sftp, fabric

I'm wondering if there's any way to connect `SFTP` server with Windows' Command Prompt, by only executing batch file.
Do I need to install additional software? which software?

The purpose is to do pretty basic file operations (upload, delete, rename) on remote `SFTP` server by executing a batch file.

And by the way, I have heard about `python`'s `Fabric` library, and I wonder whether it's better solution than the batch script for the mentioned basic file operations?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: We use psftp where I work.

Answer (score 1):

The built in FTP command doesn't have a facility for security. You can use winscp, an open source free SFTP client and FTP client for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). It allows to set up file transfers from the command line and supports SSL.

See http://www.unixlore.net/articles/using-curl-for-ftp-over-ssl-file.html